# Как выполнить команду в Anaconda Prompt из кода Python (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda

При разработке телеграм-бота через telebot появилась задача отправить две команды в терминал Anaconda Prompt на винде, но из кода Python, во время его выполнения. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?
Либо может быть можно выполнить команду "conda activate simswap" через cmd? Обходным путём в общем тоже приветствуется